Select only distinct values from two tables on pgadmin without getting all combinations
I have two tables.
table 1



Column A
Column B




rgz
1


dry
1


vgy
2


chy
3


pom
2



table 2



Column C
Column D




tuv
10


tuv
11


chx
22


lmn
34



I want the following result shown on data output of postgres PgAdmin



Column E
Column F




1
tuv


2
chx


3
lmn



I just want to be able to select distinct values from column B of table 1 and column C of table 2 and show the results as above. I do not want all possible combinations which I can get by the following query
select * from (select distinct column B from table 1) a, (select distinct column C from table 2) b 

Can you please suggest a way to do this?
Thank you
G.

You seem to want only values that appear more than once. Since you won't know which side is longer you'll need a full join to pair them up:
with A as (
    select columnB, row_number() over (order by min(columnB)) as rn
    from Table1
    group by columnB
    --having count(*) > 1 /* filtering for duplicates was unnecessary */
), B as (
    select columnC, row_number() over (order by min(columnC)) as rn
    from Table2
    group by columnC
    --having count(*) > 1 /* filtering for duplicates was unnecessary */
)
select columnB, column C
from A full outer join B on B.rn = A.rn;


Thank you Very much. Appreciate your help.
